# Is xmatters open source? is there any documentation or a website where it explicitly says that xmatters is or isn't open source?

Tags: xmatters

I am a part of a dev team and the company requires us to work only with non open source software, but I am unable to find out if xmatters is open source or not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines. If you have a question about a specific product or project's licensing, contact that product vendor or project directly. We are not their licensing support staff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full disclosure, I work for xMatters. 
xMatters as a product is a closed source solution, but our integrations are "open source" under various licenses. More info can be found at https://xmatters.com